# Save image to Android Gallery with libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I created a folder with a png file on the sd of my smartphone using the function ScreenUtils and PixmapIO of libgdx. This folder is not recognized by the Andorid gallery.

This is my code.

```
byte[] pixelData = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixels(true);
Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), Format.RGBA8888);
ByteBuffer pixels = pixmap.getPixels();
pixels.clear();
pixels.put(pixelData);
pixels.position(0);
PixmapIO.writePNG(file, pixmap);
```

The folder with the file is on my sd-card, but the default Android Gallery doesn't show them.

Comment: maybe phones problem.did you tried on other devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [`MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener%29) to notify the system of new media files.